# Registering a click event with Sammy

Tags: javascript, events, click, handlebars.js, sammy.js

I am trying to create the following behaviour with my Sammy-driven application:

[image]

The image describes a gallery-view, and is created through [Sammy](http://sammyjs.org/) and the templating framework [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com). Each element has the following template:

```
<article class="gallery-item">
    <img src="{{url_thumb}}" alt="{{title}}" id="image-{{id}}" />
</article>
```

The burgundy colored square to the left (2) is supposed to show the large version of it's pink twin to the left.

How do I wire up the event so that when I click an element with class ´gallery-item´, the image on the right is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you structure the application as presented in this blog post: [mvc med sammy og handlebars](http://open.bekk.no/mvc-med-sammy-og-handlebars/). You would make a gallery-item view, and a gallery view. The gallery view would contain the gallery item views and a preview view for the image on the left side. It would then need to attach an click event listener with help of for example jQuery.

Something like this:

```
var that = this;
$(".gallery-item").on(function(e) {
   that.previewView.showImage("send in the url to the image that where clicked on, 
   or a model containing the url or whatever you like!:)");
}
```

For more information on how jQuery:on works, check out [jQuery API:ON](http://api.jquery.com/on/)